# Getting Warning "Time Series is deprecated. Please use Series.". Please let me know how to use series for this Error

Tags: python, analytics

I wrote a small Analytic logic using Python. When I am trying to use predict  function it is throwing me the following warning

"FutureWarning: TimeSeries is deprecated. Please use Series return TimeSeries(result, index=self.predict_dates)"

Following is the small code snippet

```
results = model.fit(5)
predictedset=results.predict("2016-04-18 22:00:00", "2016-04-   21 21:00:00")
```

I am getting the Error When i use "result.predict()"

Please suggest me how to use series for Predict Function